# Virtual host for subdomain without trailing directory

Tags: xampp, cakephp-3.0, virtualhost

I have setup my virtual host for my subdomain on my windows 10 server using xampp. The subdomain working but it pointed to my folder(where i put my cakephp app) instead of just my subdomain like below;

```
sub.mydomain.com/cake
```

what i want is

```
sub.mydomain.com
```

this is my virtual host setting

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/cake/"
    ServerName sub.mydomain.com
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/cake/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

also there is a index.php file inside the htdocs folder with this content

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/cake/');
    exit;
?>
```

is there any settings that i missed to configure?

Comment: If `C:/xampp/htdocs/cake` is the root of your application install (that is, it has folders like `src`, `vendor`, `plugins`, `tmp` and `logs`), then what you really want as your DocumentRoot is `C:/xampp/htdocs/cake/webroot`.

Comment: And surely you don't want to redirect to a URL with `/cake/` appended if you don't want `/cake/` appended to your URL.